# How to get Flight Training outside Starfleet in the TNG era?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

How to get Flight Training (and an according rating) during the TNG era for persons who did not want to join Starfleet but were inhabitant of a planet within the Federation?

We have, as an example, Kasidy Yates(-Sisko). In her [biography on Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kasidy_Yates-Sisko), it is not mentioned with any word that she was part of Starfleet at any point. Nontheless, she was allowed to operate for Starfleet and in their controlled space. On the other hand, it would be too dangerous to let anybody without any training take control over a Warp capable ship.

So, how was it determined who's allowed to fly a Warp capable ship in Federation space and where was it possible to get the necessary ratings?

Comment: Starfleet is the navy. It doesn't cover all (or presumably even the majority of) ships. In our world, countries have their navies, but also have merchant navies/merchant marines, which are non-military ships such as cargo and passenger vessels; there's certainly a Federation equivalent.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, but if you want to pilot a boat, I need a license (at least in Switzerland where I come from). Ând we don't even have a sea but only lakes.

Comment: There are endless references to merchant vessels; https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Special:Search?query=merchant&scope=internal&contentType=&ns%5B0%5D=0&ns%5B1%5D=4&ns%5B2%5D=112#

Comment: @Valorum But how do the pilots get their training / rating?

Comment: @Shade - You have to remember that each planet in the Federation is an independent entity within a wider Federation of planets. Each one likely has its own (local) defence force, merchant navy, cargo ships, etc with their own attendant flight schools, training bases and apprenticeships.

Comment: "it would be too dangerous to let anybody without any training take control over a Warp capable ship" — says who? As per [page 11 of the original TNG Writers/Directors Guide](http://www.roddenberry.com/media/vault/TNG-WritersDirectorsGuide2.pdf#page=16), Starfleet isn't a police force. It's not their job to enforce who should be doing what across the galaxy.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite In order to drive a car / motorbike, you need a license. Same with piloting a boat. If you want to pilot an airplane, it costs you around CHF 120k (EUR 110 / USD 130) to get the license. Piloting a space vessel with a matter / anti-matter reaction which can, as seen in several scenes, be used as a bomb, is certainly more demanding than any of the previously mentioned tasks.

Comment: @Shade - You don't need a licence to drive a boat. You do need various local licences to do various local things

Comment: It is a bit of a plot hole considering any space ship could be turned into an extinction level event if it crashed in the real world.

Comment: @Shade it doesn’t cost me that, because I don’t live in Switzerland. At the risk of blowing your mind, Star Trek’s premise is that space and Switzerland are actually different. To quote some old guy who wrote books, space is big. Really big. You just won't believe how vastly hugely mind-bogglingly big it is. I’ll bet you a whole bag of quatloos that the Federation can’t be enforcing space flight laws even just within Federation space. If you want to land on a planet, or dock at a space station, maybe _they_ have requirements.

Comment: @lucasbachmann: maybe not _any_ space ship. If the Enterprise’s warp core detonated on your planet, that’s probably bad. Smaller, slower ships? Maybe not so much.

Comment: @Valorum - At the risk of pedantry, you do in fact need to obtain a license before piloting a boat in some jurisdictions, such as France (engines over 6 hp).  Also, numerous states in the US require that boaters pass a test and carry a card proving such; because violation of this requirement is subject to a fine, this is the functional equivalent of a license requirement.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yes, they are very different. It was only an example. But as a Swiss, I know Swiss law and requirements and not those of to European Union / United States or whereever. And it's not everywhere the same. However, we have the STCW Convention (International Convention on Standards of Training, Certification and Watchkeeping for Seafarers) that regulates standards for maritime training. Therefore, not everybody can captain a ship on earth. I somehow can't imagine that the federation goes "Everybody can maintain, pilot and captain a ship with a potential anti matter bomb in it."

Comment: @Rob - I think you've answered your own point. Some jurisdictions require licensing. Note that in Voyager Tom needs to go to flight school before crossing a certain territory in order to get an appropriate flight status. The same is likely true on certain planets in the Federation.

Comment: @Shade: sure, although I don’t think we’ve established how dangerous small ships are in Star Trek. And with space being big (and planetary defence being a thing), I’m not sure the risks of letting people jump in ships outweigh the freedom to go explore. If we’re looking for a real-world comparison, I think [The Law of the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_sea) might be the place to start.

Comment: And to quote Wikipedia, “ The convention also codified freedom of the sea, explicitly providing that the oceans are open to all states, with no state being able to subject any part to its sovereignty. Consequently, state parties cannot unilaterally extend their sovereignty beyond their EEZ, the 200 nautical miles in which that state has exclusive rights to fisheries, minerals, and sea-floor deposits. "Innocent passage" is permitted through both territorial waters and the EEZ, even by military vessels, provided they do no harm to the country or break any of its laws.”

Comment: Not to dismiss the risks of incompetent people lurching around the galaxy at warp speed, but the Federation wouldn’t exist if someone had stopped Zefram Cochrane from getting drunk and strapping himself to a somewhat-poorly-constructed light-speed rocket.

Comment: `Microsoft LCARS Space Sim v2340` - or something like that

Comment: @Valorum - I probably not only answered my own point, but I also agreed with you while yet contradicting: local jurisdictions' rules vary and sometimes you do need that license.  I suppose that must also be true of Federation planets, but supposition isn't canon.

Comment: Should I point out that any pilot today is getting *Flight Training outside Starfleet in the TNG era*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The earliest look we have at civilian warp ships is in Star Trek Enterprise.  The back story of Ensign Mayweather was that he was born to a space faring family/clan aboard the freighter ECS Horizon. It is mentioned that most freighters of that time were owned and operated by family clans who took care of their own training.
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/ECS_Horizon

We know something called a Master's License or Master's Ticket existed by at least the TOS era.  In the episode *Mudd's Women*, Harry Mudd is impersonating Leo Walsh who holds a valid license while Harry's was revoked.
[https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Master's_License](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Master%27s_License)

During the Star Trek: TNG/VOY/DS9 era, several places are mentioned as part of various characters' backgrounds or service records.  These include Starfleet Academy, Vulcan Flight School, The Daystrom Institute and Trill pilot school (where Jadzia Dax earned a level 3 license).
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lower_Decks_(episode)
https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Playing_God_(episode)

On the humorous side, in the Star Trek: Voyager episode *Natural Law*, Tom Paris is sent to pilot school by an alien race after he gets picked up for reckless flying. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708934/characters/nm0680392

Answer (score -1):

Canonically there is no real answer one can presume that Yates and other non Starfleet citizens of the Federation are accredited somehow but honestly there is no real requirement for them to be especially if they stay in known space where an autopilot can take care of flying the ship.

The closest answer would be we really dont know there might not even be an age restriction since Paris was teaching a two year old to fly however anti-matter to power a warp core probably isnt easy to get which means only someone who can get anti-matter can realistically fly a warp capable ship.

As to training we see many instances of the holodeck being used for pilot training one can assume that if an accreditation is required it would be possible to acquire one much like a driving test is used to get a license today